# How to keep the cursor style when Chrome's DevTools are undocked into a separate window

Tags: css, google-chrome, cursor, google-chrome-devtools

I was working on an html page, previewing it on Chrome (version 83.0.4103.61), trying to figure out why my custom cursor style wasn't working. It was supposed to turn into the "move" cursor when clicking and dragging around the page, but the cursor was only changing, for a brief moment, after releasing, and before moving the cursor around. I ended up realizing this only happens when I have Chrome's Developer Tools opened, and undocked into a separate window.

This is my code:

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

body:active {
  cursor: move;
}
```

This undesired behaviour cannot be reproduced in CodePen. It also does not happen with Firefox, or Edge. But it does happen if you run the above code snippet here, on Stack Overflow, with Chrome's DevTools undocked.

Any idea why this happens, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Try enabling "emulate a focused page" in options, https://puu.sh/FQYAd/2be254a7bd.png

Comment: It  worked. Thanks! New problem: How can I save these settings, so that I don't have to do it every single time I start working?